# Why am I getting this error-msg: Warning in postgresqlQuickSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, pool, r-dbi

I am using the package `pool` for a Shiny-app, which establishes a connection to my PostgreSQL-DB. From time to time i am getting the error-msg below without the app running. Also when I run the code locally, the same error appears, and sometimes repeatedly.

> Warning in postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :   Could not
>   create execute: SELECT 1 Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn,
>   statement, ...) :    RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: no
>   connection to the server )

Is it because pool creates a connection to the DB and after some time the DB (or server) gets disconnected because of a time-out?

Anyway, nowhere in my code I am making an SQL-query which has `SELECT 1` inside.

- Is the query coming from pool itself (The `validateQuery()`)?
- How can I prevent this error?

In my ShinyApp I have also the following code to end the pool connection after the App was closed:

```
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    pool::poolClose(pool)
  })
```

---

Furthermore, when running the ShinyApp, the App works fine & behaves as expected. But when I close the App, **RStudio often crashes** and I have to reopen it and reload the Project.

- Why is that?
- How can I find out what caused the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to be doing anything with the `pool` inside server.R other than CRUD stuff. You should only create/destroy the pool inside global.R. In other words, the pool is created once when the app launches and is shared among all users' sessions. It is only closed when it is no longer needed, which is when the app shuts down.

**global.R**

```
pool <- dbPool(...)

onStop(function() {
  poolClose(pool)
})
```

Comment: I am creating the pool in a global.R file. Inside the server I am just reading and writing to the DB. But you're right, that I was trying to destroy the pool inside the server. I will try with the `onStop` function. Thanks for your answer.